# Nested For Loops and outputting asterisks

Tags: c++

i have to write a c++ program that asks the user to enter an integer *k* and then outputs k lines of asterisks with the first line starting at 1 asterisk and the last line finishing with k asterisks.

i can get the program to output a square of asterisks such as:
(k=5)

```
*****
*****
*****
*****
*****
```

when it should look like this:

```
*
**
***
****
*****
```

how should i adjust my program to accomplish this?
(Note: i have to use two for loops.)

```
int main() {
    int k, cols, rows;
    cout << " Please enter a number: ";
    cin >> k;

    for (cols = 1; cols < k + 1; cols++) {
        for (rows = 1; rows < k + 1; rows++)
            cout << "*";
        cout << endl;
    }

    getchar();
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The inner loop should run `col+1` times. So you need change the condition in the inner loop to `rows < cols` and have `rows` be one less than `cols` by changing its starting value to `0`:

```
for (cols = 1; cols < k+1; cols++) {
    for (rows = 0; rows < cols; rows++)
        cout << "*";
    cout << endl;
}
```